# Chrome Extension | Load content script from external source to chrome extension on button click

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension, where I am trying to load content scripts [list of javascripts] from external source, to the. chrome extension on a button click.

Right now all my content scripts are resides inside a S3 bucket.

On button click, I am passing message, from popup to background and storing the content of the javascript inside the chrome.storage.local. Following is the code :

popup.js

```
const saveBtn = document.getElementById("save-btn");
saveBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ msg: "fileSave" });
});
```

index.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg) => {
    if (msg.msg === "fileSave") {
        console.log("Im am running - if");
        //download file from s3 object url and save in js object
        fetch("https://scripts.s3.test.com/test.js")
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    console.log("SUCCESS");

                    return response.text();
                } else {
                    console.log("Not Successful");
                }
            })
            .then((fileData) => {
                fileContent = eval(fileData);
                chrome.storage.local.set(
                    {
                        fileContent: fileContent,
                    },
                    () => {
                        console.log("File content is stored to storage");
                    }
                );
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log("ERROR", error));
} else if (msg.msg === "printFetched") {
        chrome.storage.local.get("fileContent", function (result) {
            console.log("resultHere", result);

            if (result.fileContent) {
                fileContent = result.fileContent;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Now on chrome tab update, I am trying to load the javascript from chrome storage to the chrome.tabs.executeScript. The code for this is as below :

background.js

```
 chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
            console.log("fileContent inside execute", fileContent)

            if (changeInfo.status == "loading") {
                for (let i = 0; i < listOfScripts.length; i++) {
                    let scriptName = listOfScripts[i].name;
                    let pattern = listOfScripts[i].listOfPattern;
    
                    console.log(scriptName, "?", isMatch(pattern, tab.url));
    
                    if (isMatch(listOfScripts[i].listOfPattern, tab.url)) {
                        chrome.tabs.executeScript(
                            tabId,
                            { file: "source/jquery.js" },
                            function () {
                                chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { **file: fileContent** })
                            }
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

But it is treating the fileContent as text, not as javascript & throwing the error **"Unchecked runtime.lastError: No source code or file specified."**

Work around tried :

1. Used   chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: eval(fileContent) })
2. Used chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: new Function(fileContent)() })

I want to load the list of script into my extension and execute them on tab update.

Please help me guys